# SpringBoot / Thymeleaf - can't delete hashmap key

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to create a delete button for each value from an hashmap, but it's not working... :-(
I have use a logger in de controller method :
->>  HomeController : Removing weight null from user    :-(

Spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteValue", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteValue(Principal principal, Long key, ModelMap modelMap) {
    User user = authService.extractUserFromAuthInfo(principal);

    user.deleteValueByKey(key);

    userDAO.save(user);

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

User Model

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "user_timeline", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@MapKeyColumn(name = "date")
@Column(name = "weight")
private Map<Long, Double> weights;

...

public void deleteValueByKey (Long key) {
    weights.remove(key);
}
```

Thymeleaf (Normally, the problem is here)

```
<tr th:each="weight : ${user.weights}">
    <td>
        <form method="POST" action="/deleteValue" modelAttribute="user">
        <input type="hidden" th:value="*{weight.key}"/>
        <button type="submit">X</button>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by _"it's not working"_? What specific problems or errors are you seeing? If you have not already done so, take a look at [ask].

Comment: i don't know if it's beter...

Comment: You can inspect the browser's HTML (which was generated by Thymeleaf) and see if the Thymeleaf variables have been replaced by your expected data. You can even edit the HTML in the Thymeleaf template, if you need to, so that the data is displayed (or fails to be displayed) in visible `<div>`s.

Comment: How are you passing your Java `user` data into the context used by Thymeleaf to populate `${user.weights}`?

Comment: I have use a logger in de home controller method : HomeController          : Removing weight null from user    :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem :
It was missing **name="key"** in the input line

```
<form method="POST" action="/deleteValue">
    <tr th:each="weight : ${user.weights}">
        <input type="hidden" name="key" th:value="${weight.key}"/>
        <button type="submit">X</button>
    </tr>
</form>
```